# How can I add blank columns to the results of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-null

I'm working on a query that pulls demographic information for people who have visited a location. However, the fields required for this report aren't all available in the DB, and some will need to be added manually from a separate Excel file after I've exported the results of my query. The person who will be responsible for merging the two files asked if it would be possible to create blank columns so they can more easily see where the missing data needs to go, and I wasn't sure how to go about that. Obviously those blank columns could just be created in the exported spreadsheet, but I wondered if there was a way to add them in the SQL query itself.

My `SELECT` statement currently looks something like this—I've just added comments to mark the missing fields so I can keep track of what order all the fields for this report need to be in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
PersonID,
PersonFName,
PersonLName,
PersonDOB,
VisitID,
--StaffFName,
--StaffLName,
FacilityPhone,
FacilityAddress,

...and so on
```

Since those two staff name fields don't exist in my DB, I obviously can't actually include them in the `SELECT` list. But is there a way to still include those two fields as blank columns in my query results? Something along the lines of "`select [nothing] as StaffFName`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add literal `nulls` to the `select` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PersonID,
    PersonFName,
    PersonLName,
    PersonDOB,
    VisitID,
    null as StaffFName,
    null as StaffLName,
    FacilityPhone,
    FacilityAddress,
...
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use empty strings instead:

```
...
    '' as StaffFName,
    '' as StaffLName,
...
```

But `null` is the canonical way to represent the absence of data.

Comment: Awesome, I'd hoped it would be something as simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: The type of these `NULL`s will be `INT`. Although most clients shouldn't care, in some cases it may be necessary to `CAST` the `NULL`s to `VARCHAR`s of appropriate length anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good to know. Since we're just trying to create blank fields for the Excel merge right now, the data type doesn't really apply, but that's useful information for future reference.